# Convertir código php a perl

Tags: perl

¿Cómo puedo convertir el siguiente código de PHP en perl(logicamente estoy haciendo CGI y el módulo session de CGI)?

```
if(isset($_POST['userLogin'])){

    $email=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['email']);
    $pwd=md5($_POST['pwd']);
    $sql="SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE email='$email' AND password='$pwd'";
    $run_query=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($run_query);

    if($count==1){
            $row=mysqli_fetch_array($run_query);
            $_SESSION['uid']=$row['user_id'];
            $_SESSION['uname']=$row['first_name'];
            echo "true";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

No lo he probado y seguro que se puede mejorar, pero para que te hagas una idea de por dónde van los tiros:

```
use DBI;
use Digest::MD5 qw(md5 md5_hex md5_base64);
use CGI qw();
use CGI::Session;
$session = CGI::Session->new();
$CGISESSID = $session->id();

my $c = CGI->new;
my $email = '';
if ('POST' eq $c->request_method && $c->param('userLogin') && $c->param('userLogin') ne '') 
{
    $email = $c->param('userLogin');
}
else
{
    print false;
    exit;
}
my $db      = 'DBI:mysql:database=DATABASE;host=HOST';
my $dbuser  = 'USER';
my $dbpwd   = 'PASS';
my $dbh;
$dbh = DBI->connect($db, $dbuser, $dbpwd)
my $query = "SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE email=?"
my $c = $dbh->prepare($query);
$c->execute($email);

$pwd = md5($pwd);
while(my $row = $c->fetchrow_hashref())
{
    if($row->{password} eq $pwd)
    {
         $session->param('uid', $row->{password});
         $session->param('uname', $row->{first_name});
         print true;
    }
}
```